# _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>')

Tags: json, list, flutter

I have this error and I saw more topic but I can't get to solve it.

my model :

```
class JobModel {
final String title;
final int id;
final String slug;
final String content;

JobModel(this.title, this.id, this.slug, this.content);
```

and this is how I try to fetch data

```
Future<List<JobModel>> _getJobs() async {
var response = await http.get(
    "...?pathname=/anunturi/pagina-1&userID=");
Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
List<dynamic> data = map["context"];
return data;
}
```

and I get the error on this line `List< dynamic > data = map["context"]`

print(map) :

```
{context: {categories: [{id: 15, title: Auto-Moto, slug: auto-moto, content: Vanzari-cumparari de automobile, piese acte. Anunţurile sunt destinate zonei Radauti-Suceava<br />, related: {link: /anunturi/auto-moto-15, archiveLink: /arhiva-anunturi/c/auto-moto-15, deletedPostCount: 387, postCount: 22}}, {id: 16, title: Diverse, slug: diverse, content: , related: {link: /anunturi/diverse-16, archiveLink: /arhiva-anunturi/c/diverse-16, deletedPostCount: 189, postCount: 18}}, {id: 17, title: Electronice/electrocasnice, slug: electronice-electrocasnice, content: Vanzari, cumparari, inchirieri de aparate electronice şi electrocasnice. Calculatoare, camere digitale, componente, accesorii, telefoane GSM, camere video, playere DVD, etc.
I/flutter (11118): , related: {link: /anunturi/electronice-electrocasnice-17, archiveLink: /arhiva-anunturi/c/electronice-electrocasnice-17, deletedPostCount: 70, postCount: 3}}, {id: 19, title: Imobiliare, slug: imobiliare, content: <p>Vanzari, cumparari şi &icirc;nchirieri de apartamente, case, ter
```

Comment: What is an example of the expected response?

Comment: Well response is from when I tryed with DIO and didn't change the variable name

Comment: please post at least the structure of the expected JSON, or just `print(map);`

Comment: I'll post print(map) in like 10 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Map<String, dynamic> map` object is of type `Map<String, dynamic>` and not `List<JobModel>`. You will need to convert the map that you're using into a the `List<JobModel>` that you're looking for.

I'm assuming under the response object you have a field `context` that maps directly to the `JobModel` as a list and it's fields like this:

```json
{
  "context": [
    // first JobModel Map
    {
      "title": "some title here",
      "id": 1234,
      "slug": "some slug value",
      "content": "the rest of the object content",
    },
    // second JobModel Map
    {
      "title": "some other title here",
      "id": 5678,
      "slug": "some other slug value",
      "content": "blah blah,",
    },
  ]
}
```

Your class/`job_model.dart` should look something like this.

```dart
class JobModel {
  final String title;
  final int id;
  final String slug;
  final String content;

  JobModel(this.title, this.id, this.slug, this.content);

  // for converting your object into a json object
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'title': title,
        'id': id,
        'slug': slug,
        'content': content,
      };

  // for init from a json object.
  JobModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : title = json['title'],
        id = json['id'],
        slug = json['slug'],
        content = json['content'];
}
```

and then when fetching, it should be used like this:

```dart
Future<List<JobModel>> _getJobs() async {
  // Looks like the example response above I gave
  var response = await http.get(
      "...?pathname=/anunturi/pagina-1&userID=");
  
  Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  List<JobModel> jobList = List<JobModel>();
  jsonResponse.forEach((jsonJob) {
    // using the constructor we made earlier
    JobModel job = JobModel.fromJson(jsonJob);
    jobList.add(job);
  });
  return jobList;
}
```

You should provide more information on the response itself to get a better solution for your case.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but now I get null value on `print(jsonResponse[0]['title']);`

Comment: Based on your `print(map)` result, your response isn't formatted correctly. I looks as if the response fields aren't enclosed in double quotes (`"`). For example, `context: {categories: [{id: 15, title: Auto-Moto` should be `"context": {"categories": [{"id": 15, "title": "Auto-Moto"` for this solution to work.